# .htaccess add trailing slash after domain

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-301

How can I re-inforce the forward slash after domain - situation like this:

```
http://www.domain.com
```

to become

```
http://www.domain.com/
```

At the moment I have something like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$ [NC] [AND]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(.*)\.domain\.com$ [NC]  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

I've tried different things, but cannot get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

`http://example.com` and `http://example.com/` are the same URL.  You don't need to do anything at all.  See [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) for details.

**Edit:** Because this is inexplicably being voted down despite being completely correct, please see [section 6.2.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-6.2.3) in particular:

> the following four URIs are equivalent:
>
> - http://example.com
> - http://example.com/
> - http://example.com:/
> - http://example.com:80/

Comment: Well - that's not quite true. If you do the SEO you'd find out that these are two different pages / locations and you're content will be found as a duplicate by search engines.

Comment: No, that's completely wrong.  You're probably thinking of the difference between `http://example.com/foo` and `http://example.com/foo/`.  The question regards the root of the domain.  Those URLs are identical.  They refer to the exact same resource.

Answer (score -2):

Most if not all browsers add the `/` by default. However browsers recently decided to hide the `http://` and the `/` after from the user (it however still sends them). The other thing is that mod_dir which is installed in pretty much all apache installations already does a 301 redirect if the `/` is not present. So I thing you want to solve something that isn't a problem to begin with.

Comment: Apache already does the job. Check the HTTP header, and you will see.

Comment: Apache does the job if the mod_dir is installed - otherwise this has to be re-inforced in some way and I need to make sure that it does work either way. So do you - or do you not - know the syntax to force it using htaccess?

Comment: apache without mod_dir, is pretty useless in most cases. I'm not wasting my time creating a solution to a hypothetical problem that never occurs in real life, and that isn't even a problem to begin with (google knows domain.com is the same as domain.com/).